# Getting a Integer From Pointer Warning in string[strcspn()] Situation

Tags: c, string, string-comparison

I'm using this function to remove newline characters from a string:

```
void remove_newline(char *string) {
    string[strcspn(string, "\r")] = "\0";
    string[strcspn(string, "\n")] = "\0";
}
```

The interesting thing is that I'm getting a warning when I try to compile this:

> warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast

Why I'm getting such warning in this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"\0"` is a *string literal* and defines a character array of `{'\0', '\0'}`. It decays to a pointer if used without index. This pointer in turn then you are trying to assign to `string[...]` which is an 8 bit integer, a`char`, hence the warning

> assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast

To code a single character, a *character literal*, use single quotes: `'\0'`